# MS VC++ OpenSSL SSL_read() blocking

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ssl, openssl, http-post

I am trying to send an HTTP-POST request from C++ over SSL/TLS using OpenSSL implementation. The following implementation works except for the `SSL_read()` part. `SSL_write()` successfully returns the number of sent bytes, but the `SSL_read()` simply blocks the program execution.

Any idea what's going wrong?

```
SSL_CTX *ctx;
SSL *ssl;
char buf[1024];
int server, bytes, recv;

SSL_library_init();
ctx = InitCTX();               // Custom Function   
server = OpenConnection();     // Custom Function
ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
SSL_set_fd(ssl, server);

ostringstream FormBuffer;
FormBuffer << "POST " << FormAction << " HTTP/1.1\n";
FormBuffer << "Host: " << Host << "\n";
FormBuffer << "User-Agent: " << UserAgent << "\n";
FormBuffer << "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n";
FormBuffer << "Content-Length: " << ContentLength << "\n\n";
FormBuffer << "username=USER&password=PWD\n";
const auto str = FormBuffer.str();

if (SSL_connect(ssl) != -1)
{
    bytes = SSL_write(ssl, str.data(), str.length());
    recv = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf)); // <--- BLOCKING !!!
    ...
    SSL_free(ssl);
}
```

Comment: How are you sure server sent the response? May be server didn't respond and hence SSL_read is not having anything to read and return.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, going to check that ...

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to SSL.
You send the header part of the POST request to the server, but not the body (the data for posting). But the server will only respond once it received and processed the request body. This means that your read from the server will simply block because no data are sent by the server.

Comment: I actually send the body with the request (check updated question). I just forgot to include that line to my initial question. Either way I think that i should get an html page as a response? But the SSL_read() just blocks.

Comment: Are you sure that the ContentLength is correct (It's not visible how you compute it)? And it should be `\r\n` and not `\n` as the line end although lots of servers (but not all) accept the wrong line end too.

Comment: Ok thanks, content length is correct, already verified that ... I'm going to give it a try with `\r\n` line endings.